# Wordpress outputting full image instead of thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have a script that displays the first 5 images uploaded to a post. However, the output displays each image as the full url rather than the thumbnail, so the loading time takes longer than required. Please can someone let me know where I am going wrong with this script?

The website is: http://tessabunney.functionpixel.com/projects/

The script is:

```
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' ); 
function theme_setup() { 
    add_image_size( 'multimedia-thumb', 220, 180, true ); 
}

function echo_first_image( $postID ) {
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 5,
        'order' => 'DEC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_parent' => $postID,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
    );

    $attachments = get_children( $args );

    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'multimedia-thumb' )  ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'multimedia-thumb' ) : wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'multimedia-thumb' );

            echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID ) . '" class="current">';
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare in your theme/functions.php ? if not WordPress won't generate the thumbnails
Example

```
add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true );
```

Then in your theme calls like now. Also, you must try to force to regenerate thumbnails with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Yes, I have tried it before but have left it with my custom size 'multimedia-thumb' for you to see it doesn't affect it.

The code I am using is updated above and I have re-regenerated the thumbnails just encase :)

Comment: Try to do this to know if it's really adding
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
function theme_setup() {
  add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true );
}

Comment: did you server support GD library in PHP? Create an info.php file with <?php echo phpinfo();?> and find gd support

Comment: That maybe the issue but I'll leave this for now as the site will be moving to another server in the next few days. I will be back! :)